# Error en mi LoadModel

Tags: c#

Me sale un error al querer consumir uno de mis servicios *SelectModelsByProductCode*.

Me dice que **no se ah dado ningun argumneto que corresponda al parametro requerido ProductCode**.

```
   private void LoadModel()
   {
       try
       {
        List<Model> items = ParseItem.ParseArrayToList(this.ws.SelectModelsByProductCode());
           

       }
       catch
       {

       }
   }
```